# EventEmitter trouble in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I try to emit an event from child component to parent, just like in Angular's manual described here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

My **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SquareService } from './services/square.service';
import { Square } from './models/square';

@Component({
    selector: 'squares',
    template: `
        <square *ngFor="let square of squares"
                (click)="square.select()"
                (notify)="onNotify($event)"></square>
    `,
    providers: [SquareService],
    directives: [Square]
})
export class AppComponent {
    squares: Square[];

    constructor(private squareService: SquareService) { }

    // UPD added
    processSquare(row: number, col: number) {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
        this.coords = this.cols[col] + (8 - row).toString();

        return this;
    }

    // Nevermind
    ngOnInit():any {
        this.squares = this.squareService.genSquares();
    }

    // Cant get here =(
    onNotify(event):void {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

and child component **square.component.ts**:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'square',
    template: `
        <span>nevermind</span>
    `,
    directives: [Piece],
})
export class Square {
    @Input() square: Square;
    @Output() notify: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    public isSelected = false;

    select() {
        this.notify.emit(null);
        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    }
}
```

Shortly, I have the chess **squares**, I wanna highlight the one I clicked on and unhighlight the others. So I should iterate through all squares and set **isSelected** property to false. But the event just does not emit. I see nothing in console.

UPD **square.service.ts**:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Square} from "../models/square";

@Injectable()
export class SquareService {
    /**
     * Generates the squares for the board
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    genSquares() {
        let ret = [];

        for (let row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (let col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                let square = (new Square).processSquare(row, col);
                ret.push(square);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an implementation of your `SquareService`?

Comment: I think you're mixing up View and Controller here. You generate `Square` classes, which are also components, then iterate through them with `ngFor`, which again will create new `Square` components. Reading your code is really confusing and you might want to think about an architectural change.

Comment: I updated the question by adding the square.service.ts , and processSquare method. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your template to this, and magic will happen:

```
<square *ngFor="let square of squares"
    (click)="squareComp.select()"
    (notify)="onNotify($event)"
    [square]="square"
    #squareComp>
</square>
```

You are calling `select()` on a `SquareModel` and not on the `SquareComponent`. And you did not bind the `squareModel` on your `squareComponent`..

Comment: God, it works! Thanks a lot. What part of the documentation I get missed?

Comment: You didn't miss anything regarding `EventEmitter`. Just property and template binding :). Calling `[square]="square"` will bind the `squareModel` on the `@Input()` variable of the `squareComponent`. And `#squareComp will bind the `squareComponent to the template variable `squareComp`, which then you can use within the template, to call the `squareComp.select()` method. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I should notice one thing. The **PierreDuc**'s method works, but now in the **square.component.ts** the command `this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;` does not work, because this is referred to the component itself, not to the Square. So now we need pass the square from the template to the method:

```
<square *ngFor="let square of squares"
        [square]="square"
        [class.selected]="square.isSelected"
        (click)="squareComp.select(square)"
        (notify)="onNotify($event)"
        #squareComp></square>
```

and trait like this:

```
select(square: Square) {
    square.isSelected = !square.isSelected;
}
```